# Objects used as ENUS via as const

Tags: typescript

In my team we decided to not use ENUMS (:sad:) but implement them via the keyword `as const` on an object.

I am having a problem with a type definition when I use `as const`.

The error makes sense to me (image below).
The LEFT SIDE expects type 'type' but the RIGHT SIDE is a string.
`types.WARNINGS` is the value of the object, which is a string. So the two are not compatible.
What do you suggest to fix this error?

[image]

```
export default function App() {
  const types = {
    SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
    WARNING: "WARNING",
    ERROR: "ERROR"
  } as const;

  const getIcon = (type: typeof types): string => {
    if (type === types.WARNING) {
      return "A";
    }
    if (type === types.ERROR) {
      return "B";
    }
    return "C";
  };

  const myIcon = getIcon(types.WARNING);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{myIcon}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-bush-ebjxc?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Your `types` is an *object*. `typeof types` will give you the type of the *object*. You want the keys instead.

```
const getIcon = (type: keyof typeof types): string => {
```

But I'd prefer to make another mapping of types to icons.

```
const types = {
    SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
    WARNING: "WARNING",
    ERROR: "ERROR"
} as const;
const iconsByType = {
    SUCCESS: "A",
    WARNING: "B",
    ERROR: "C"
}
const getIcon = (type: keyof typeof types) => iconsByType[type];
```

You might also consider using a slightly less ambiguous name to avoid confusion - perhaps `status` instead of `types`.

Comment: Thanks!
On a minor note, do you have any opinion on the debate `ENUMS` vs `OBJECTS as const` ?

Comment: I really prefer using plain objects instead of enums, mainly because objects and arrays in native JS work just as well, and I don't see the need for another data structure - but others have different opinions.